# Why does cat works and file open object doesn't?

Tags: python, subprocess, file-descriptor

Why does this work:

```
diff = subprocess.Popen(['cat','foo.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pr = subprocess.Popen(sublime, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stdin=diff.stdout)
pr.wait()
if pr.returncode == 0:
    msg = pr.stdout.read()
    print "message : %s" % msg
    er = pr.stderr.read()
    print er
```

But this doesn't:

```
diff = subprocess.Popen('open("foo.txt","r")', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am trying to launch sublime from command line terminal and pass the text entered in sublime to a variable.

What bothers me I can achieve with the first one but it will not work on windows!

Comment: Popen is specifically for opening executables. If you want to rub python objects in a sub process, maybe try multiprocessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `cat` is a *shell* command, but `open` is a Python function. `subprocess` with `shell=True` invokes something like bash (and with `shell=False`, it does roughly what bash also does, but with less extra parsing) - so, basically, it can run any command you can run directly in a terminal without having to open another process (like the Python interpreter) first. You *could* do something like:

```
subprocess.POpen(r'python -c "open(\"foo.txt\", \"r\")', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but that's a bit ridiculous.

The reason the first code doesn't work on Windows is because Windows has no `cat` command. But you can do what you're trying to achieve without invoking any other subprocess than sublime - essentially, the equivalent of doing `sublime < foo.txt` rather than `cat foo.txt | sublime`.

To do this, read the data from the file into a variable *first*, then send it to the subprocess using `communicate`:

```
sublime = subprocess.POpen(['sublime'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
data = open("foo.txt", 'rb').read()
out, err = sublime.communicate(data)
```

Comment: even if I write something in sublime the variable contains nothing in out or err.

Comment: @Ivc : I tried the same code changing the text editor to `nano` which gave me this error `Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM` and when I trid `vim` i got this error and shell is stuck `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`

Comment: @san nano and vim both read from STDIN only if you give them the filename `-` - ie, do ``POpen(['nano', '-'], ...)`. It is possible that sublime does the same. since this is a common Unix convention. Also, double check that you are giving the same arguments to sublime in this method as in your original code. But convincing it to dump its data to STDOUT shouldn't depend on how its STDIN is generated.